# Specifying several +cmd arguments to :tabedit from within Vim

Tags: vim, vi

How can I do something like `:tabedit +norm\ Go +star +set\ dir=/ filename` from within Vim ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the command separator:

```
:tabedit filename | exec 'norm! Go' | startinsert | set dir=/
```

From a practical standpoint, for a single file, it is faster do do

```
:tabe filename↪
:set dir=/↪
Go
```

---

I misread your question the first time; I thought you were talking about running multiple commands from the shell when opening up vim because you had the `+…` syntax (which is only applicable when opening vim from the shell, as `+` is a flag … an alternative to `-c`—see `man vim`)

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one `+cmd` argument, but nothing prevents you from concatenating multiple Vim commands via the command separator `|`. Note that some commands cannot be directly concatenated (among them `:normal`; cp. `:help :bar`) and need to be wrapped in `:execute`:

```
:tabedit +exe\ "norm\ Go"|star|set\ dir=/ filename
```